# How to get rid of the highlighted background in inputs and textarea when a form is auto completed?

Tags: html, css

I would like to make the inputs and textarea to stay transparent when a form is auto completed. Here is an example below:
[image]

Thanks in advance for the help...

HTML:

```
<form class="form appear appear-hidden" method="post">
    <h1>Contact Me</h1>
    <div class="name-section">
      <input name="name" type="name" placeholder="Name" required />
      <input name="name" type="surname" placeholder="Surname" required />
    </div>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required />

    <textarea
      name = "message"
      type="message"
      placeholder="Message"
      row="4"
      required
    ></textarea>

    <input class="submit" type="submit" placeholder="submit" />
  </form>
```

CSS:

```
form input {
  width: 98%;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  /* background-color: #000; */
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might have a similar problem I ended up finding the solution. Here it is:

CSS:

```
form input:-webkit-autofill,
form input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
form input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
form input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white !important;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```